# ajax testing using htmlunit

Tags: ajax

I am using HtmlUnit for automated testing of my web application that application is not working properly because of asynchronous nature of ajax. I used NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController but it seems it is not working because my application is using multiple threads for retieving data.

> Is there any alternative.
>   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to call.

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
```

or

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
```

before accessing fields modified via ajax.

If that don't solve try to explicitly wait for a condition that is expected be fulfilled when your JavaScript runs

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (condition_to_happen_after_js_execution) {
            break;
        }
        synchronized (page) {
            page.wait(500);
        }
    }
```